# Simultaneously toggling 2 divs in 1 container + 2 in another container

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure how to search for this: on a gallery page I want to be able to toggle the image between its original size and 2x by clicking on it **but also** by clicking a zoom button in another container which changes state (indicating you can either zoom in or out in concordance with the image div current state)

I got as far as toggling the image by clicking it or the button but I don't know how to also toggle the button.

Thanks.

Comment: could you include your code? and/or what you have tried

Comment: I edited a bit of the code I had found before and I'm getting the effect I wanted! I'm not sure how good this solution is, any improvement suggestions would be cool. I feel happy for now though.

[http://jsfiddle.net/Qb9rS/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/Qb9rS/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `toggleClass()`. For example http://jsbin.com/uhiguv/1/edit

And with also using `hasClass` you can target the elements specifically. For example: http://jsbin.com/uhiguv/2/edit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style>
  .image.active{width:64;height:64;}
  .active{border:2px solid black;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

  Click the image or the button<br><br>

  <img 
    class="ctrl image"
    src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f9dc5de7822b1679d7133691ec616174?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG">

  <br><button class="ctrl button">Grow</button>

<script>
  jQuery(function(){

    $('.ctrl').bind('click', function(){

      $('.ctrl').toggleClass('active');

      if ($('.ctrl.button').hasClass('active')) {
        $('.ctrl.button').text('Shrink');
      }
      else {
        $('.ctrl.button').text('Grow');
      }

    });

  });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great! this is what I want but how could I use this making the button as images?

Comment: use css `.button.active{background-image:url('/img/shring.jpg')` and `.button{background-image:url('/img/grow.jpg')`